# Deduce End date from a list of StartDate

Tags: sql

I have the following data table

```
| Activity | ID | StartDate  |
| A     | 1  | 10/02/2021 |
| A     | 2  | 11/02/2021 |
| A     | 3  | 12/02/2021 |
| B     | 1  | 08/02/2021 |
| B     | 2  | 10/02/2021 |
```

And I would like to add another column corresponding to the EndDate, with the EndDate of one ID being the StartDate of the next.
So it means the following result:

| Activity | ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10/02/2021 | 11/02/2021 |
| A | 2 | 11/02/2021 | 12/02/2021 |
| A | 3 | 12/02/2021 | ?? |
| B | 1 | 08/02/2021 | 10/02/2021 |
| B | 2 | 10/02/2021 | ?? |

I thought about doing somehting like that, but obviously it doesn't work

```
SELECT *,min(StartDate) from t
WHERE (SELECT StartDate from t WHERE t.Activity=Activity AND t.StartDate>StartDate)
GROUP BY
```

It doesn't feel too difficult but I can't seem to find the way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select activity, id, startdate,
       lead(startdate) over (partition by activity, id order by startdate) as enddate
from t;
```